# protractor select values from drop down implemented using mat-select

Tags: typescript, xpath, css-selectors, protractor, angularjs-e2e

I am looking to write a protractor method that will select values from this drop down. The drop down holds 4 values, one of which is "Delta". How do I select values from this selector as this does not have any options tag I can use .

I realized that the actual options are under another tag.How do I select the Options ? The below doesn't seem to work.

element(by.cssContainingText('mat-select-panel mat-select-content .mat-option .mat-option-text', 'Fund'))
            .click();

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is how I solved it. First I had to click the dropdown and then another click for selecting the value.

```
element(by.tagName('mat-toolbar')).element(by.tagName('mat-select')).click();
  
element(by.cssContainingText('mat-option .mat-option-text', 'Delta')).click();
browser.waitForAngular();
```

Thanks for your guidance guys. Appreciate it.

Answer (score 2):

The HTML code of the options is outside the `mat-select` node. Don't find them within `mat-select` node.

```
// click the down arrow at right side to expand options
element(by.css('mat-select#mat-select-8 .mat-select-arrow-wrapper')).click();
// choose desired option
element(by.xpath('//mat-option[.="Delta"]')).click();
```

Comment: That did not work. I found that the mat-options were written under another tag 'cdk-overlay container'. I edited my question to add a screencap of the same. I'm still having trouble figuring out how to select from the options

Answer (score 0):

[by.cssContainingText](https://www.protractortest.org/#/api?view=ProtractorBy.prototype.cssContainingText) is one solution. To get that element containing the text "Delta" you could do `element(by.cssContainingText('span','Delta'));`

Also, a similar QA (Not a dupe) might be useful to you: [dropdown select by visible text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49194963/dropdown-select-by-visible-text/49196052#49196052)

Comment: @njosep What are the error messages you are getting?